# Dataframes Calculate Multiple Columns Based one other Column - for Loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, for-loop

I'm working with multiple data frames and I am trying to perform a change the values of columns 3-9  to their value divided by the value of the third column which contains a population. I could run it manually on a single column, but would rather not do it for every column in each data frame, so I am hoping to find a for loop so I can run it on each data frame which has the same columns for each year. The columns I am trying to change are all int64, and the one I am using as the divisor is a float64.

I was thinking something like :

for column in df.iloc[:, 3:10]:
column.value() = column.value()/ df['Population']

So I can change the data frame name and run it on each, or even better I can create a function which takes the argument of the name of the data frame, but I was just hoping for this to get started. Thanks!

Comment: `for df in dataframes:
    df.iloc[:, columns] /= df["Population"]` ?

Comment: That worked! Thank you!!

for i in range(3, 10):
    df.iloc[:, i] /= df["Population"]

Comment: no for loop needed, `df.iloc[:, 3:10] /= df["Population"]` will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can create a list of dataframes:

```
dfs_list = [df, df1, df3, df4] # specify your DFs here
```

Then iterating over the columns using a forloop:

```
def update_columns(x):
    for col in x.columns[3:10]:
        x[col] = x[col] / x['Population']
```

And apply the func to each df in the list:

```
for df in dfs_list:
    update_columns(df)
```

Comment: Note that the for loop on columns is useless, you can divide them all a once.